# why are two query's inside one php tag not working

Tags: php, mysql

I have tried out some code were two mysql statement need to be executed, I don't have any syntax error though, but second mysql query is not working and not giving out any results. Please help me out am pretty new to this field if any mistake pardon me, thank you.

**.php**

```
<?php
$con = mysqli_connect("localhost", "*****", "*****", "******");
$query = ("SELECT * FROM profile");
$result = mysqli_query($con, $query);
while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
    $query1 = ("SELECT vault_no FROM  grp_tbl");
    $result1 = mysqli_query($con, $query1);
    while ($row1 = $result1->fetch_assoc()) {
        if ($row1['vault_no'] !== $row['vault_no']) {
            echo
            '<div class = "chat-user-name"><span class="pull-right label label-primary"><input name="ppl" type="radio" value= "' . $row["via"] . '" "></span><div align="center"><input type="hidden" name="category" value="macro">
                                                </div>
                                                ' . $row['via'] . ' </div>';
        }
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: Thank for edit sir..!

Comment: ok @Sandeep sir sure ill try it.

Comment: Hari, not sir here on Stack Overflow.

Comment: okay sorry @Sandeep i tried out your suggestion sadly its not working out in my case i think.!!

Comment: including != not working..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use like this, it may work

```
<?php
$con = mysqli_connect("localhost", "*****", "*****", "******");
$query = ("SELECT profile.* from profile left join grp_tblon profile.vault_no!=grp_tbl.vault_no where profile.vault_no!=grp_tbl.vault_no");
$result = mysqli_query($con, $query);
while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
            echo
            '<div class = "chat-user-name"><span class="pull-right label label-primary"><input name="ppl" type="radio" value= "' . $row["via"] . '" "></span><div align="center"><input type="hidden" name="category" value="macro">
                                                </div>
                                                ' . $row['via'] . ' </div>';
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: sure sir..!! ill try it out.

Comment: Sorry sir but you used two closing braces?

Comment: that will not make any problem, as per your code I edited, if you don't want remove it.

Comment: Call all the members by name. This will show as we are all same.

Comment: thank you @ mani can i ask how exactly it works in my case.?? because i never used a join before.!

Comment: I understand  what you want exactly, because I suffered like this lot of problems like this.

Comment: please if you wont mind, can you explain how this joins work..!! any source is also okay, coz i am wanting to learn it..

Comment: Join is nothing but, the connection between two or more tables. check here http://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-inner-join.aspx

Comment: Why do you have the same criteria in the on clause and in the where clause as well?

Comment: @Shadow: Because if we not used where , all rows will execute in left side, if it is not matched with right table also left table execute and right table having null value. But Hari need to avoid left table also, that's why we used where condition.

Comment: If you wont mind..can you please help me resolve this-> " http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37784065/a-static-data-being-stored-for-every-dynamically-generated-fields-and-submit-but " issue

Answer (score 2):

I think the best approach is to use LEFT JOIN on your query as below:

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM profile LEFT JOIN grp_tbl ON profile.vault_no <> grp_tbl.vault_no ORDER BY profile.YourOrderField";
```

I hope that one helps

Comment: get back to me in case of any problem. I will give you another solution  based on your code

Comment: If you wont mind..can you please help me resolve this-> " http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37784065/a-static-data-being-stored-for-every-dynamically-generated-fields-and-submit-but " issue

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using nested queries and php loops, use [join](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/join.html) in the sql query, a left join in this case:

```
select profile.*
from grp_tbl
left join profile on profile.vault_no<>grp_tbl.vault_no
order by profile.via
```

Although it is unclear what exactly you are trying to achieve in the inner loop.